# Vulkan cause segment fault on termination. Why?

Tags: c++, vulkan

**Context**

Trying to make a minimal example with Vulkan, I get a segmentation fault on termination. All the examples I found are very similar but i still get the crash.

**Tries**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>
int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    // Application info
    VkApplicationInfo appInfo = {};
    appInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO ;
    appInfo.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_0;
    appInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION( 0 , 0 , 1 ) ;
    appInfo.pApplicationName = "test_vulkan" ;
    appInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    appInfo.pEngineName = "test_vulkan";

    // Instance info
    VkInstanceCreateInfo instanceInfo = {};
    instanceInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    instanceInfo.flags = 0;
    instanceInfo.pApplicationInfo= &appInfo;
    instanceInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    instanceInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = nullptr;
    instanceInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = nullptr;
    instanceInfo.enabledLayerCount =0;
    instanceInfo.enabledExtensionCount = 0;

    // Create instance
    VkInstance instance = nullptr;  
    VkResult res = vkCreateInstance( &instanceInfo, nullptr, &instance); // null is the allocator for host

    if (VK_SUCCESS==res) cout << "Instance created with success" << endl;
    else cout << "Failed to create instance" << endl;


    if (instance)
    {
        vkDestroyInstance( instance , nullptr ) ;
        cout << "Instance destroyed" << endl;
    }
    instance = nullptr;


    return 0;
}
```

**Question**

What is causing this segmentation fault?

**Computer specs:**

- Debian Jessie 8.8
- Graphic card: Nvidia 1050Ti with driver 375.66

**Related**

[vkCreateInstance causing a segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604097/vkcreateinstance-causing-a-segmentation-fault)

Comment: Have you tried running the code under a debugger? It may break at where the fault is.

Comment: Sure, it just crash with "Segmentation fault" on the return statement.

Comment: @AdrianMaire 1) On the `return 0`? Unlikely. Make sure you compile in debug mode 2) Try if the `cube` demo runs fine (Or better try VIA from the SDK) 3) Try the [beta drivers](https://developer.nvidia.com/vulkan-driver)

Comment: Thanks, I will try 2)&3). `return 0` is not that unlikely, if the driver or any object fail to release itself, it will crash on the return. I know I am in debug because I am able to break just on the return statement.