# vkCreateInsatance segmentation fault

Tags: c, glfw, vulkan

I followed by [vulkan tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Introduction), and i get segfault on vkCreateInstance.

I use arch (btw), and i install vulkan by `paru -S vulkan-devel` (also linux-firmware and mesa are installed). My CPU is AMD Ryzen 7 2700, and GPU is Radeon RX 580 4GB.

I saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604097/vkcreateinstance-causing-a-segmentation-fault), but the answer did not solve my problem (and besides, they use C++, not C)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

const char* APPLICATION_NAME = "Vulkan Teach";
const uint16_t WIDTH = 800;
const uint16_t HEIGHT = 600;

static GLFWwindow* window;
static VkInstance instance;

void error(char* message, int code) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s (status code: %d)\n", message, code);
    exit(code);
}

void initWindow() {
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, APPLICATION_NAME, NULL, NULL);
}

void mainLoop() {
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}

void createInsance() {
    VkApplicationInfo appInfo;
    appInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    appInfo.pApplicationName = APPLICATION_NAME;
    appInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
    appInfo.pEngineName = "No Engine";
    appInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
    appInfo.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_0;

    VkInstanceCreateInfo createInfo;
    createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    createInfo.pApplicationInfo = &appInfo;

    uint32_t glfwExtensionsCount = 0;
    const char** glfwExtensions;
    glfwExtensions = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&glfwExtensionsCount);

    createInfo.enabledExtensionCount = glfwExtensionsCount;
    createInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = glfwExtensions;

    createInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0;

    VkResult result = vkCreateInstance(&createInfo, NULL, &instance);
    if(result != VK_SUCCESS) {
        error("Failed to create vulkan instance.", result);
    }
}

void initVulkan() {
    createInsance();
}

void cleanup() {
    vkDestroyInstance(instance, NULL);

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
}

int main() {
    initWindow();
    initVulkan();
    mainLoop();

    cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most probably passing uninitialized values to your instance creation. This part of the code:

```cpp
VkInstanceCreateInfo createInfo;
createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
createInfo.pApplicationInfo = &appInfo;
```

Only initializes the `sType` and `pApplicationInfo` members of the create info, while other important members such as `pNext` are uninitialized and as such may contain values that the driver doesn't know how to handle, resulting in the segfault.

So as a general rule for all (Vulkan) structs: Zero initialize like this:

```cpp
VkInstanceCreateInfo createInfo = {0};
```

Comment: I write code in pure C, and i cannot create structure at this way.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I'm not 100% sure if this works with pure C, but if not, my answer is still valid as you have to properly initialize all Vulkan structures. If you can't zero initialize, just explicitly set all fields of the create info.

Comment: Yep, it's works in pure C. Anyway, i just added pNext, and it's worked!